# Facebook comment plugin in Hybrid mobile app not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I am using this plugin on my website. This will enable people to write their comment on fb comment box. 
This link will give you the comment plugin code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator

Then I try adding it on my hybrid mobile app.

Here is an example code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

At first I have an error here. I just changed this line:
`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";` **to**  `js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";`

The error disappeared but still the comment box doesn't show.
They say it should not be run locally and you need to host your html file on a server.

If hybrid app don't have a host (just local file), how can I show the comment box?